# upper semi-continuous of fuzzy set

Tags: fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

Let $u:\mathbb{R^n}\to [0,1]$ be a fuzzy set. (fuzzy set is a set of ordered pairs $(x,u(x)), x\in \mathbb{R^n})$.
Please give an example such that  $u(x)$ be upper semi-continuous. thanks

Comment: What is a fuzzy set in your book?

Comment: Since not every function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $[0,1]$ is upper semi-continuous, you have to define what you mean by a fuzzy set.

Comment: I don't know of any requirements for fuzzy sets membership function to be upper semi-continuous. Take any indicator function of an open set. Those are perfectly valid membership functions for a fuzzy set, and they are all lower semi-continuous. I agree with @Wuestenfux, something is missing.

Comment: @user809500 Thank you for clarifying. Conversely to what I said in my previous comment, the indicator function of a closed set is upper semi-continuous. What are examples of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{x} = \{x_i\}^n_{i=1}$. The indicator function of the unit ball defined as
$$u(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert_2 = \left( \sum^{n}_{i=1} x_i^2 \right)^{1\over2} \leqslant 1$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
is upper semi-continuous. Another example would be
$$v(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $0 \leqslant x_i \leqslant 1$ for all $i$}\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
which would be the indicator function of a unit (hyper-)cube, also upper semi-continuous (thanks to the $\leqslant$ in the expression)

Note: this makes $(\mathbf{x},u(\mathbf{x}))$ and $(\mathbf{x},v(\mathbf{x}))$ examples of "crisp" fuzzy sets. They map $\mathbb{R}^n\to \{0,1\}$ which is a special case of $\mathbb{R}^n\to [0,1]$. If you need something with "more fuzziness", I can offer
$$w(\mathbf{x}) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{1+(\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert_2)^2}  & \text{if $\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert_2 \leqslant 1$} \\ \frac{1}{1+4(\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert_2)^2} & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$